Bounding the cdf in the weak Berry-Esséen theorem
(Berry-Esséen theorem, weak form) Let $X$ have mean zero, unit variance, and finite third moment, and let ${\varphi}$ be smooth with uniformly bounded derivatives up to third order. Let ${Z_n := (X_1+\ldots+X_n)/\sqrt{n}}$, where ${X_1,\ldots,X_n}$ are iid copies of ${X}$. Then we have
$\displaystyle {\bf E} \varphi( Z_n ) = {\bf E} \varphi(G) + O( \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} ({\bf E} |X|^3) \sup_{x \in{\bf R}} |\varphi'''(x)| )$
where ${G \equiv N(0,1)_{\bf R}}$.
In the reverse direction, consider the cumulative distribution function $\displaystyle {\bf P}( Z_n < a )$ of ${Z_n}$. For any ${\varepsilon > 0}$, one can upper bound this expression by $\displaystyle {\bf E} \varphi(Z_n)$, where ${\varphi}$ is a smooth function equal to ${1}$ on ${(-\infty,a]}$ that vanishes outside of ${(-\infty,a+\varepsilon]}$, and has third derivative ${O(\varepsilon^{-3})}$.
By this construction one can eventually conclude that
$\displaystyle {\bf P}( Z_n < a ) = {\bf P}( G < a ) + O( \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} ({\bf E} |X|^3))^{1/4}$.
Question: How can we assume the third derivative of $\varphi$ to be $O(\varepsilon^{-3})$? It is hinted that this follows from the definition of $\varphi$, and that it may help to first change variables to $\varphi(x) = \varepsilon^{-1} \int_{-\infty}^0 \eta( x - t/\varepsilon)\ dt$ and then differentiate under the integral sign to see this. Isn't it simply the result of three applications of the mean value theorem?
